# tcp_probe module does no output

Tags: networking, ubuntu, tcp

I'm trying to plot the TCP congestion window and the slow start threshold using iperf and the tcp_probe module. I do exactly what is told here:

to obtain the data:

```
modprobe tcp_probe port=5001

chmod 444 /proc/net/tcpprobe

cat /proc/net/tcpprobe >/tmp/tcpprobe.out &

TCPCAP=$!

iperf -i 10 -t 100 -c receiver

kill $TCPCAP
```

Oops!

/tmp/tcpprobe.out is empty :(

This is Ubuntu 11.04 x86

and already tried the same on Ubuntu 11.04 x64

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem. What worked for me was:

```
modprobe -r tcp_probe

sudo modprobe tcp_probe port=5002 full=1

sudo chmod 444 /proc/net/tcpprobe

cat /proc/net/tcpprobe > /tmp/tcpprobe.out &

TCPCAP=$!

iperf -c <servers IP address here> -p 5002 -t 100 -i 1

sudo kill $TCPCAP
```

See iperf parameters to check if those (-t 100 -i 1) are what you need by typing:

```
man iperf
```

Answer (score 3):

I/O function in C standard library use buffer by default, usually 4k , so fread() only return when buffer full or EOF. You can use small buffer, 128 bytes, see:

> dd if=/proc/net/tcpprobe ibs=128 obs=128

Now, message flush quickly.

Answer (score 2):

By default the tcp_probe logs only when the cnwd changes, try `modprobe tcp_probe ... full=1`.

Linux source code referece: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/net/ipv4/tcp_probe.c#L47

Comment: tried - no change ...
maybe this is because I cant unload module before load it again?
modprobe -r tcp_mode has no effect

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar issue, the tcp_probe module outputs only in non-obvious time intervals. I've created a modified version of it that flushes on every received tcp segments. This slows down the system, but allows to better monitor short-lived connections like HTTP.

Find [the source code to the module here](https://github.com/Dynalon/tcp_probe_fixed).

Answer (score 0):

another issue which causes no output is file permission of output file tcpprobe.out

when cat tcpprobe directly, it's able to see the output, but if redirecting the output the file, the output file size is 0, which reminds me that it's the permission issue...

Answer (score -1):

A very late answer, but have been struggling with this issue myself. I was trying out the version Dyna provided, yet still got no output, regardless of the parameters used. In the end, I found that the order was the problem.

The way I was using tcp_probe was: install/activate the module, run some tcp application (I was running some tcp unit tests), then start the copy process for /proc/net/tcpprobe (as shown in the other answers) and then remove/stop the module. The correct way is to start the copy process (barring killing of the process) BEFORE you perform the tcp intensive activity. Keep the cat process running while you perform the tcp activity and only kill it afterwards.

A pretty humbling experience for me, as it took hours to figure this out. Hopefully, people find this useful.